# LogIn Sharepoint UAG-Server

Tags: c#, sharepoint, session-cookies

I've written a Sharepoint Application to fetch data from a Sharepoint List with "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx". I can connect to every Sharepoint-Website but if I want to connect to this special site which got a UAG-Server behind it, i get the error "Object Moved... This object may be found here". I thought it may be a cookie problem with the authentification on the LogIn.
So I tried this, but it always gives me the same error:

```
       CookieContainer web_cookies = new CookieContainer();

       client.CookieContainer = web_cookies;
```

Is there anyway to pass the authentication on the UAG-Server?
Please help me!

Comment: Ok, i think the problem is the URL. In the debugger, the URL is not the same as the URL in my webservice, the Server automatically redirect me to another URL where i get an error: "UAG Forefront Block".

Comment: No way to pass the authentication !